# Boost converter output voltage drops

Tags: voltage, power, current, buck, boost

I'm using an [MIC2251 (MIC2251-1YD5-TR)](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/268/MIC2251_High_Efficiency_Low_EMI_Boost_Regulator_DS-1954827.pdf) in a design to boost a lithium battery (3.6V-4.1V) to 5.4V for powering a small camera peripheral that requires a typical draw of 80mA. I expect that the worse case current supplied needs to be about 2x 80mA due to efficiency and the switched voltage boost. I followed the reference design from Figure 5-1 on page 10.

I'm using the recommended capacitances and inductance values of 10uF on input (C1), Cff of 2.2 uF, and L = 10 uH or 4.7uH. My R1 is 910k and R2 is 270k. Output voltage with a load resistance of 1k Ohm is as expected at Vout = 1.24(R1/R2 + 1) = 1.24*(3.37+1) = 5.42V. As this load is increased output voltage drops to 5.2 at load of 462 Ohm, 4.99V at load of 231 Ohm.

I've tested the following inductors:
Sumida CDRH2D18/LDNP-4R7NC 4.7 uH with Isat of 630mA
Bourns SRN3030HA-4R7Y 4.7uH with Isat 2.4A
Bourns SRN3030HA-100M 10uH with Isat 1.6A

R1 is Yageo RC0805JR-07910KL 910k ohm
R2 is Yageo RC0805JR-07270KL 270k ohm
Cinput is Samsung CL21A106KOQNNNG
Cff is Samsung CL21B225KPFNNNE
Diode is Diodes Inc 1N5819HW-7-F

The reference design show a boosted output of 15V at 100mA from a Li-ion cell so I believe my application is well within the capabilities of the regulator. I suspect the inductor may be the limiting factor, but for a light load the saturation seems sufficient? Can you help me to understand which component of element might be giving me problems and suggest a replacement?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us a pic of your layout too.

Comment: @brhans, added my layout too

Comment: @brhans, should I change my value of R1 to 100k as suggested in the table 5.1 on page 10?

Comment: Some junctions on your schematic have dots to indicate a positive connection but, some don't and therefore cannot be assumed to be connected. Looking at the wire entering on the left to C4, it's clear you haven't used a sensible grid size and, in fact, you may have grid snap turned off <-- this can create a significant connectivity problem.

Comment: Yes, you should follow the manufacturer's guidance there unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: There are also a few issues with your layout. C4 should be closer to the inductor - move it to the other side of the IC, right next to the inductor. You've been very stingy with the ground vias. When you move C4 over, give it its own vias (more than one is better). Also route a track directly from pin-2 of the IC over to C4's ground pad. And why have you split the ground plane on the bottom side?

Comment: You need to look at reducing the loop length and impedance of the main current paths. So that's current from C4, through the inductor, into the IC's SW pin, out the IC's GND pin, and back into C4.